# Location - latitude longitude format for youtube data v3 api - api explorer

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to find youtube videos by their latitude, longitude and locationRadius.

Youtube data api docs- do mention about this parameter.
[image]

But when I try to use the exact same format in the api explorer,

What should I do?

[image]

It gives this silly error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to YouTube Data API v3 [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) `part` is mandatory but it's not the case and `type=video` seems mandatory while not being described as such.

So the following works: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?location=37.42307,-122.08427&locationRadius=12km&type=video&key=YOUR_API_KEY

> The type parameter restricts a search query to only retrieve a
> particular type of resource. The value is a comma-separated list of
> resource types. The default value is video, channel, playlist.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> - channel
> - playlist
> - video

As spotted by [@Probosckie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2095022/probosckie) `channel` and `playlist` don't seem to work with my solution.

Comment: thanks, yes i tried to search for a similar example in the docs and modify it. the type is mandatory

Comment: If my answer completely answers your question don't hesitate to confirm my answer likewise anybody can quickly see that your question has a validated answer.

Comment: if i try to use another type apart from video - then this query fails- it only works with type video - not with channel or playlist. - please include that in your answer.